# What is the natural linearization on differentials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field. Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over $\Bbbk$. Let $X$ be a scheme over $\Bbbk$. Let $G$ act on $X$ with the action morphism $\sigma:G\times X\to X$. There are two morphisms from $G\times X$ to $X$
$$\sigma:G\times X\to X,\quad \mathrm{pr}:G\times X\to X.$$

For $\mathcal F$ a (quasi-coherent) sheaf on $X$, a linearization is an isomorhpism
$$\phi:\mathrm{pr}^*\mathcal F\xrightarrow{\cong}\sigma^*\mathcal F$$
satisfying a suitable cocycle condition.

When $\mathcal F=\mathcal O_X$, there is a canonical linearization. Canonically we can identify $\mathrm{pr}^*\mathcal O_X\cong\mathcal O_{G\times X}$ and $\sigma^*\mathcal O_X\cong\mathcal O_{G\times X}$ and $\phi:\mathrm{pr}^*\mathcal O_X\to \sigma^*\mathcal O_X$ under these identification is the identify $1_{\mathcal O_{G\times X}}:\mathcal O_{G\times X}\to\mathcal O_{G\times X}$.

.

When $\mathcal F=\Omega_{X/\Bbbk}$, there should also be a canonical choice of $\phi:\mathrm{pr}^*\Omega_{X/\Bbbk}\to\sigma^*\Omega_{X/\Bbbk}$. However it is unclear to me at the moment.

Can you describe what is the canonical $\phi:\mathrm{pr}^*\Omega_{X/\Bbbk}\cong\sigma^*\Omega_{X/\Bbbk}$
?

Comment: The same question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4551731/421127) got ana answer.